# Could sharing resources in Azure bring down an App Service?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-app-service-plans, azure-appservice

Consider having two Azure App Services sharing the same App Service Plan and thus the same resources.
Is it possible due to high traffic, error or memory leak that one App Service could bring down the other by pulling all resources?

How about an S-tier App Service which has the staging/deployment slots? Could one of those slots bring down the whole App Service?

Comment: @Peter you should convert your comment into an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Consider having two Azure App Services sharing the same App Service Plan and thus the same resources. Is it possible due to high traffic, error or memory leak that one App Service could bring down the other by pulling all resources?

Yes, and since slots use the same resources this also applies to deployments to a slot. If you want to avoid that think about containerization and limit the max memory and cpu usage or use seperate App Service Plans.